# when I pass data to a component I get undefined

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios

well,I have Context in nextjs project where I work on modals and I put modal details in the array(modalBase), also I get data from another context(toolsContext) into this context to pass data to components, but When I console data in this context it's given me data but in the components, after passing data to components it gives me undefined, I am confused

```
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [modals, setModals] = useState([]);

  const router = useRouter();
  const query = router.query;

  const { collectionData } = useContext(toolsContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const ss = await collectionData(query.taskId);
      setData(ss);
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  // ======= Modal details
  const modalsBase = [
    {
      name: "collectCreator",
      openStatus: false,
      content: <CollectionForm />,
    },
    {
      name: "taskItemCreator",
      openStatus: false,
      content: <TaskItemForm data={data} />,
    },
    {
      name: "taskCreator",
      openStatus: false,
      content: <TasksForm data={data} />,
    },
    {
      name: "collectionEdit",
      openStatus: false,
      content: <CollectionEditForm data={data} />,
    },
    {
      name: "taskItemEdit",
      openStatus: false,
      content: <TaskItemEditForm />,
    },
    {
      name: "tasksEdit",
      openStatus: false,
      content: <TasksEditForm />,
    },
  ];
```

I think that I get this problem because I have components in the array and I try to pass data to components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` is undefined in your components because you're initializing it asynchronously in a `useEffect` hook, and then immediately using it in your `modalsBase` array. Remember that `useEffect` is executed after the component render, and fetching the data is also an asynchronous operation.

This means that when your `modalsBase` array is being defined, `data` is still `undefined`. It only gets a value after the data fetching has completed, and by this time, your `modalsBase` array has already been defined with `undefined` data.

To fix this issue, you should move your `modalsBase` array inside a `useEffect` hook that has `data` as a dependency. This way, the array will be redefined every time `data` changes. Here's how you can do it:

```js
const [modals, setModals] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const modalsBase = [
    {
      name: "collectCreator",
      openStatus: false,
      content: <CollectionForm />,
    },
    {
      name: "taskItemCreator",
      openStatus: false,
      content: <TaskItemForm data={data} />,
    },
    // ...
  ];

  setModals(modalsBase);
}, [data]);
```

Now, `modalsBase` is redefined every time `data` changes, which includes the initial fetch. The components will receive the updated `data` correctly.

Also, I recommend initializing `data` as `null` instead of `undefined` to make it more explicit that it is intentionally empty at the start. That way, you can use conditionals to render different things based on whether `data` is `null` or has a value. You can do this by changing the line `const [data, setData] = useState();` to `const [data, setData] = useState(null);`.

Remember that this will cause a re-render every time `data` changes. If `data` changes frequently, you might want to consider a different approach, such as passing a loading state to the components, or fetching the data inside the components themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your great reply!!! you save me, I will definitely consider this all advice